# Deriving the magnetic field due to a dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I am trying to follow along with a derivation from Cullity, *Introduction to magnetic materials* 2011. I am getting stuck at a very early stage when computing the components of the magnetic field at a point P due to a magnetic dipole at the origin, where P is at an angle $\theta$ from the direction of the dipole's magnetic moment (in a 2D plane). See diagram:

[image]

I compute

$H_r = \frac{m \rm{cos}(\theta)}{r^3}$.

However, they compute

$H_r = \frac{2m \rm{cos}(\theta)}{r^3}$.

See bottom of diagram for the equations in the textbook. Or see the book chapter here

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470386323.app1.

Why do the have $2 \times$ what I calculate for $H_r$? Are we not simply taking the cosine of the field, to find the field along from the line from the centre of the dipole to P?

Answer (score -1):

the magnetic field on the axis of the dipole is $2KM/r^3$
here dipole is $M$
in the general case, which you are talking about, the axial dipole is $Mcos(\theta)$
so the magnetic field on the axis of $Mcos(\theta)$ dipole will be $2KMcos[\theta]/r^3$
just replaced $M$ with $Mcos[\theta]$.

here 2 comes because of the formula of magnetic field on the axis of dipole moment, the derivation of the formula is attached in the image file, I have done the derivation in analogy to the electrostatics.
[image]
hope my answer helped you in any way.
thank you, this is my first answer on this app.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Making a tour in the site you'll realize that answers scanned images of bad handwritten math equations are not acceptable.